# How do I install MS SQL Server 2008 R2 or 2012 Standard Edition on Windows 8.1

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have had problems in doing this and getting errors all the time at the end.  I am running Windows 8.1.  So, I was wanting to learn more about SQL Server 2012 through training offered on Lynda.com.  However, they reference a prerequisite course on MS SQL Server which was published prior to the release of MS SQL server 2012.  Before I list the problem I am having let me ask, if I installed MS SQL Server 2012 or later, would I still be able to follow that course based on SQL Server 2008 R2 - at least well enough to be able to move on to courses that cover "new features" in later editions of MS SQL Server.  Some software is easy enough to follow if you know one version the next version is easy enough to pick up and learn the new features.

Ok, then my next question is regard to credentials.  Whether Installing 2012 or 2008 R2, I am asked for a username and password.  With Windows 8.1, I just have one user id on my system at that is linked by an hotmail email account and password that I use when logging into the system. When installing the sql server components it asks for user account and a password.  While it appears that my account is identified by my hotmail account, within Windows, I have username Bruce/Bruce, along with Administrator, etc.  It doesn't accept those credentials.  At one point it told me that my username could not be found - it was found at the beginning of setup but not later upon completion or launching.
         Can someone help me figure out what to do, please?  Where to go for detailed steps... where to go to setup or change user accounts/passwords... with Window's Metro interface and the requirement that each user or account needs to have an email address associated with it and this must be recognized by the server.  Again, I only have one account that I setup and that was linked to and identified by my hotmail email account.  Windows Access Control sees this as being represented by my name, not my email.  I'm not sure how MS SQL Server wants the accounts for each service to be setup with passwords.
Thanks,
Bruce

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed my text got displayed wrong after the first paragraph.  I hope it is still readable or I can repost it.

Comment: You can always [edit] your own posts to fix formatting. You might do so, for instance, to break that huge wall of text into multiple paragraphs so people can read it. Hopefully, you don't speak like that in one long rambling speech without taking a pause for breath. If you do, I assure you people are too busy watching you turn blue to listen to what you're saying. :-) Text needs a little break occasionally to breathe, too.